# Array of objects is undefined when page is rendered. Potential confusion when pages re-render

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to React and I'm currently struggling with this concept that I cannot seem to find a fix for. I have to components, Parent and Child. The Parent component is passing data to the Child component via props. I can see the data is being transferred when the page is first rendered, but I've noticed in the console, that the second and third render of the page, the array comes back as undefined. I do not understand why the array is undefined, is it because I'm not setting the state in the child component?

Child component code:

````
export class NumOfDaysTable extends Component {
    static displayName = NumOfDaysTable.name;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            headers: [["Number", "Type", "Customer Name", "Customer", "Code", "Amount", "Date Submitted", "Notes", "Status"]],
            data: props.dataParentToChild
        };

    }
    render() {
        const { data } = this.state;
        console.log( data)
        const { headers } = this.state;
        
        return (
            <div>
                <h4 > {this.props.title} </h4>
                <Container>
                    <Table size="sm">
                        <thead>
                            {headers.map((headerData) => (
                                <tr>
                                    {headerData.map((headerRecord) => (
                                        <th>{headerRecord}</th>
                                        
                                    
                                    ))}
                                    </tr>
                                    ))}
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                            
                            {data.map((item) => ( 

                                
                                <tr>
                                     {item.map((record) => ( 
                                       <td>{record} </td> 
                                   ))}               
                                </tr>
                             ))} 

                        </tbody>

                    </Table>
                </Container>

            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default NumOfDaysTable; ```
````

Comment: You don't want to reassign your props to localized state, this is probably what's causing your bug. Check out https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: I'm very confused, now then when I started so maybe that's progress haha. According to the documentation and if my understanding is correct, I want to use componentDidMount to set the data and then map over it in my Render. However, when I add that, my error is still the same. I'm still getting an undefined error.

Comment: hey I get it, no worries. 
To be clear though, don't try and assign props to local state, whether that's in the `constructor` or `componentDidMount`. Props should just be "accepted" by the child component. Perhaps the data is `undefined` initially, so you might need to add a guard before trying to access that data.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reassign your props to your state, you'll lose reactivity when data is updated.

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            headers: [["Number", "Type", "Customer Name", "Customer", "Code", "Amount", "Date Submitted", "Notes", "Status"]],
            // data: props.dataParentToChild --- REMOVE THIS LINE
        };

    }
```

And then adjust your render function

```
    render() {
        const  data  = this.props.dataParentToChild;
        console.log( data)
        const { headers } = this.state;
// ...REST OF CODE
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is basically the order in which our React Component get executed. Only for initial render, there is no data and we need to handle that in our project.

You need to render your component by setting a condition that, `Only when data is passed to the Component render it.` I have used `{data && (<div>...</div>)}` in my Child component:

**Here is the working solution:**

***Parent Component:*** : Passing Props

```
import React from "react";
import NumOfDaysTable from "./StackOverflow";

const dataParentToChild = [
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 1,
    title:
      "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    body:
      "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto",
  },
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 2,
    title: "qui est esse",
    body:
      "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla",
  },
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 3,
    title: "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
    body:
      "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut",
  },
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 4,
    title: "eum et est occaecati",
    body:
      "ullam et saepe reiciendis voluptatem adipisci\nsit amet autem assumenda provident rerum culpa\nquis hic commodi nesciunt rem tenetur doloremque ipsam iure\nquis sunt voluptatem rerum illo velit",
  },
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 5,
    title: "nesciunt quas odio",
    body:
      "repudiandae veniam quaerat sunt sed\nalias aut fugiat sit autem sed est\nvoluptatem omnis possimus esse voluptatibus quis\nest aut tenetur dolor neque",
  },
];
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home Page</h1>
      <NumOfDaysTable
        title="Reality Check"
        dataParentToChild={dataParentToChild}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

***Child Component*** :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
export class NumOfDaysTable extends Component {
  //   static displayName = NumOfDaysTable.name;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      headers: [
        [
          "Number",
          "Type",
          "Customer Name",
          "Customer",
          "Code",
          "Amount",
          "Date Submitted",
          "Notes",
          "Status",
        ],
      ],
      data: props.dataParentToChild,
    };
  }
  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    const { headers } = this.state;
    console.log("Data Coming from the prop");
    console.log(data);
    return (
      <div>
        {data && (
          <>
            <h4> {this.props.title} </h4>
            <section>
              <table size="sm">
                <thead>
                  {headers.map((headerData) => (
                    <tr>
                      {headerData.map((headerRecord, index) => (
                        <th key={index}>{headerRecord}</th>
                      ))}
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                  {data.map((item) => (
                    <tr key={item.id}>
                      <td>{item.title} </td>
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </section>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NumOfDaysTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must defined data in your parent component.

Have a look in [codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/array-of-objects-is-undefined-when-page-is-rendered-potential-confusion-when-pages-re-render-3d9kn?file=/src/App.js)

```js
// Parent component example

import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import NumOfDaysTable from "./NumOfDaysTable.js";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NumOfDaysTable
      dataParentToChild={[
        [1,"Type 1","Customer 1","Name 1","Code 1","Amount 1","Date 1","Notes 1","Status 1"],
        [2,"Type 2","Customer 2","Name 2","Code 2","Amount 2","Date 2","Notes 2","Status 2"],
        [3,"Type 3","Customer 3","Name 3","Code 3","Amount 3","Date 3","Notes 3","Status 3"],
        [4,"Type 4","Customer 4","Name 4","Code 4","Amount 4","Date 4","Notes 4","Status 4"]
      ]}
    />
  );
}
```

And don't forget unique keys for your component with iteration !

```js
// NumOfDaysTable.js
// code...

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    console.log(data);
    const { headers } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <h4> {this.props.title} </h4>
        <div>
          <table size="sm">
            <thead>
              {headers.map((headerData, id) => (
                <tr key={"headerData" + id}>
                  {headerData.map((headerRecord, id) => (
                    <th key={"headerRecord" + id}>{headerRecord}</th>
                  ))}
                </tr>
              ))}
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {data.map((item, id) => (
                <tr key={"item" + id}>
                  {item.map((record, id) => (
                    <td key={"record" + id}>{record}</td>
                  ))}
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

// code...
```